# Woocommerce include custom stylesheet after woocommerce styling

Tags: css, woocommerce-offtopic

After the upgrade to WC 2.1.2 my styling seems to be overruled by the standard WC styling. Is there a way to overrule the standard WC styling without using solutions like using the `!important` or other hackish methods?

Maybe by enqueueing it in a certain way in `functions.php`?

A lot of people recommend to disable WC styles and to copy all the styles into your own theme styles. But isn't this bad if Woocommerce adds functionality?

Comment: Please use [edit]s for additional info.

Comment: Off topic...Solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

[`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) supports dependencies. So, if you make the WooCommerce style a dependency for your new stylesheet then your stylesheet will always load after the WooCommerce stylesheet.

Something like this ought to work, but it is untested:

```
function enqueue_style_after_wc(){
    $deps = class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ? array( 'woocommerce-layout', 'woocommerce-smallscreen', 'woocommerce-general' ) : array();
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', 'my-style.css', $deps, '1.0' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style_after_wc' );
```

EDIT: It turns out you don't need to use dependencies. You just need to enqueue your styles after WooCommerce enqueue's theirs.... by using a later priority.

```
function enqueue_style_after_wc(){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', 'my-style.css', array(), '2.0' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style_after_wc', 20 );
```

Comment: I had the same question 4 years later and found my own answer. I love the internet.